# Contradictory vacuous truths in consistent formal system

Tags: logic, formal-systems

Can 2 contradictory vacuously true statements be proved in a consistent formal system?

Comment: How can true statements contradict ?

Comment: Let $X = \{n \in \mathbb{N} |n<0\}$. Then both are true:

$$(P_1) \ \forall n \in X \ n = 0$$
$$(P_2) \ \forall n \in X \ n = 1$$

Comment: @Peter in a non consistent formal system there are contradictory statements which can be proved to be true, e.g. (P∧¬P)

Comment: What might help : A statement is provable if and only if it is true in every interpretation. This should be the case for vacuously true statements.

Comment: @Peter P - proved to be true statement, ¬P - proved to be true statement as well

Comment: I cannot follow, you assume a consistent formal system, an inconsistent formal system can prove everything.

Comment: @Peter I just asked your question "How can true statements contradict ?". This is how. I am interested of provability of contradictory vacuous statements in a consistent formal system.

Comment: "True" and "provable in a system" is not the same. Whether a statement is true usually depends on the interpretation.

Comment: To clarify Peter's point: truth is *relative to a model* (or *interpretation*, or *structure* - logic terminology has annoying redundancies). When a sentence $\varphi$ is provable in a theory $T$, that means (indeed, [is equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem)) that $\varphi$ is true in every model of $T$; but if we just say "$\varphi$ is true," we need to have some specific model in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vacuity doesn't enter into this at all. Consistency *means* that no pair of contradictory sentences can be proved. You're asking "Can a consistent theory be inconsistent?," and the answer to this is clearly **no** by definition.

---

That said, we *can* (and generally do) simultaneously prove statements of the form $$\forall x(P(x)\implies Q(x))\quad\mbox{and}\quad\forall x(P(x)\implies \neg Q(x)),$$ but this **doesn't** constitute a pair of contradictory statements; these two sentences can indeed be both true at the same time. Indeed, their conjunction is equivalent to $\forall x(\neg P(x))$, so we only get a contradiction if *in addition* our theory proves $\exists x(P(x))$. Indeed, this is exactly what characterizes vacuity: $\forall x(P(x)\implies Q(x))$ is a vacuous truth (with respect to our theory) iff $\forall x(P(x)\implies \neg Q(x))$ is.

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvote?